# Jquery Ajax Get external url error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

verify.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
include 'config.php';
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd, $database);
$key1 = $_GET['key1'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$phone = $_GET['phone'];
$address = $_GET['address'];
$installations = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM installations where Key1 = '$key1'");
if ($installations !== FALSE && mysql_num_rows($installations) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($installations)) {
        $key2 = $row['Key2'];
        $status = $row['Status'];
        if ($status == 0) {
            $sql = "UPDATE installations SET Name = '$name', Email = '$email', Address = '$address', Phone = '$phone',Status = '1' WHERE Key1 = '$key1'";
            mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            $data = array('key1' => $key1, 'key2' => $key2);
            echo(json_encode($data));
        } else {
            $data = array('key1' => 'key not valid', 'key2' => 'key not valid');
            echo(json_encode($data));
        }
    }
} else {
    $data = array('key1' => 'key not valid', 'key2' => 'key not valid');
    echo(json_encode($data));
}
?>
```

My Script

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "http://example.com/verify.php",
    data : {
        name : name,
        email : email,
        address : address,
        phone : phone,
        key1 : key1
    },
    cache : false,
    success : function(data) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "admin/check_verification.php",
            data : {
                key1 : data.key1,
                key2 : data.key2
            },
            cache : false,
            success : function(response) {
                $('.message_outer').fadeIn('slow').html(response);
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    location.reload();
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, exception) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            alert('Time out error.');
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            alert('Ajax request aborted.');
        } else {
            alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    }
});
```

I got 'Not connect , verify network' error. but data (name,email,address,phone,key1) saved in my server database. I'm successfully tested this code with my localhost. how can I fix this error. please help me.

Comment: can you post the code of `verify.php` ?

Comment: You're fighting the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: Is this code also running on `http://example.com` (the same domain)?

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Never** use string interpolation to accomplish this.

Comment: thanks @SLaks . I'm fixed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fixed this error, added `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` 
to my server verify.php .all thanks to @SLaks.  code from here http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-type: application/json');
include 'config.php';
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd, $database);
$key1 = $_GET['key1'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$phone = $_GET['phone'];
$address = $_GET['address'];
$installations = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM installations where Key1 = '$key1'");
if ($installations !== FALSE && mysql_num_rows($installations) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($installations)) {
        $key2 = $row['Key2'];
        $status = $row['Status'];
        if ($status == 0) {
            $sql = "UPDATE installations SET Name = '$name', Email = '$email', Address = '$address', Phone = '$phone',Status = '1' WHERE Key1 = '$key1'";
            mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            $data = array('key1' => $key1, 'key2' => $key2);
            echo(json_encode($data));
        } else {
            $data = array('key1' => 'key not valid', 'key2' => 'key not valid');
            echo(json_encode($data));
        }
    }
} else {
    $data = array('key1' => 'key not valid', 'key2' => 'key not valid');
    echo(json_encode($data));
}
?>
```

Comment: In other words, you made yet another security hole (in addition to your existing SQL injection issue).  Now, other sites can read data with the user's credentials.